# Setting default value for Python script tool properties using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, python-script-tool, parameters, tool-validation

[image]

I have a model folder which contains several shapefile, but only one named oil.shp. Is there a way to automatically set the default value for the Add Oil Layer based on the model folder and the shapefile's name? It can be done by using os.path.join(model_folder, 'oil.shp') if I don't set Add Oil Layer as one parameter. However, I want to leave the parameter there in case someone else wants to play around with another oil.shp as needed. The Script Properties comes from the Script tool.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1 Advanced License.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you would use tool validation.  I recommend reviewing [Understanding validation in script tools](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/understanding-validation-in-script-tools.htm) where the parts to pay attention to include:

> Provide default values for parameters, such as cell size for rasters.

(it has a picture)

and

> Internal validation **doesn't** do the following (but you can with your
>   own validation code):
>
> ...
>
> - Calculate default values.